# Source data doesn't match actual content when scraping dynamic content with Beautiful Soup + Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to teach myself how to scrape data and found a nice dynamic website to test this on (releases.com in this case).

Since it's dynamic, I figured I'd have to use selenium to fetch its data.

However, the retrieved page source still only contains the initial html and its `js`: not the actual elements shown in the browser.

Why does that happen?

I'm assuming it's because I'm fetching the page source, but what other option is there?

My code looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
import time

#constants
my_url = "https://www.releases.com/l/Games/2018/1/"


# Start the WebDriver and load the page
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
wd.get(my_url)

# Wait for the elements to appear
time.sleep(10)

# And grab the page HTML source
html_page = wd.page_source
wd.quit()


#Make soup
pageSoup = soup(html_page, "html.parser")

#Get data


print(pageSoup.text)
```

Comment: what element you try to get ? is it in `<iframe>` ? print `wd.page_source` to see what you get.

Comment: BTW: `Selenium` has functions to find/get elements so mostly you don't need `beautifulSoup`

Comment: you display `.text` so you get all text without tags. Use `print(pageSoup)` to see all elements.

Comment: this `pageSoup.find_all('div', class_='calendar-item')` gives me 49 elements. To get more elements you have to scroll window - and then it will load other items - and after that you can get `wd.page_source`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but that's the thing: the elements I want are the names, platforms en release dates of games found in the div "calendar-view container advanced". But neither the div, nor the titles show up in the soup (wether it's just its text or the complete thing). The Soup only contains a header, some scripts and a whole lot of gibberish.

Comment: better show your code which you use to get items.

Comment: Wait, now I feel dumb. Using Furas' find all, I can find the items. But when I did a similar thing earlier (I looked for the section "Y2016-M12 calendar-sections calendar-hidden-important" earlier), I couldn't find anything at all. 

So what is the reason the full page only shows gibberish? Is that simply because of the text's length?

Comment: page at starts shows only current items - you have to scroll window and browser will load older/newer items and then you can get page_source and you will have other items.

Comment: you can also use url wiht `/2016/12/` instead of `/2018/1/` to get `Y2016-M12`

Comment: Thanks! I tested this using the element viewer prior, and it seems to load all items for the selected month regardless, even without scrolling. So if I parameterize the year and month in the url, I should end up with a decently robust and universal scraper.

Comment: btw: in DevTool in Chrome/Firefox I see it uses this url to get new data - if you change `itemIndex=` then you get different items - but it doesn't use date to select items so it may  not be so useful. 
https://www.releases.com/calendar/PreviousBefore?blockIndex=120&itemIndex=139&category=Games&regionId=us